# Is Wilcoxon signed-rank suitable to test mean differences between two different, ordinal, variables?

Tags: likert, wilcoxon-signed-rank

My data consists of 10 perceived risks and 10 perceived benefits, measured on a Likert agreement scale. I would like to test if the means are statistically different.
It is a single sample, evaluating different risks and benefits of the same subject matter. For example, one risk concerns earthquakes and one benefit concerns job opportunities.

What would it be the best approach to achieve my aim? Would the Wilcoxon signed-rank suitable? Should I maybe think differently about the way to analyse the differences between risks and benefits?

I use R to analyse data.

Edit:
Risks and benefits concern the circumstance of moving to another country. So the same participants indicated their agreement on the risks and benefits associated with moving home. Items example: "I think that there is a high chance of potentially-damaging earthquake shaking in Cambogia"; "I think that there are several job opportunities in Cambogia" (Agreement, Likert-scale, 1-7). Basically, if the mean of benefits is higher than the mean of risk, how can I test this difference via inferential stats? Data are not normally distributed.

Visualisation via boxplots, as well as descriptives, clearly showed that the means and medians differ substantially.

Sample size: 400

Comment: This is unclear. Please explain how earthquakes and  job opportunities *benefits of the same subject matter*?

Comment: Thank you kjetil. Specifically, risks and benefits concern the circumstance of moving to another country. So the same participants indicated their agreement on the risks and benefits associated with moving home. Items example: "I think that there is a high chance of potentially-damaging earthquake shaking in Cambogia"; "I think that there are several job opportunities in Cambogia"  (Agreement, Likert-scale, 1-7).  Basically, if the mean of benefits is higher than the mean of risk, how can I test this difference via inferential stats? Data are not normally distributed.

Comment: Sample size is N = 400

Comment: Please add all this new info as an edit to the Q. Comments are easily overseen and can be deleted!

Comment: Wilcoxon doesn't compare means without some extraordinary extra assumptions.

Comment: How do you think of a mean of an _ordinal_ scale? Ordinal scale has no known metric in it.

Comment: @NickCox, thank you. So letting things open, what would it be the best/an accepted approach? An approach that would allowed me to examine if the higher level of agreement in the perceived benefits, compared to risks, did not happen by chance? When treating the variables as continuous I can see that means and medians differ substantially between risks and benefits, as well as when looking at the distribution of responses via histograms, where bars of benefits on the right side (indicating agreement) are more concentrated than in the left side, compared to risks.